# Can't modify button content of a custom template

Tags: windows-phone-7, templates, expression-blend

I'm sure this is a ridiculously easy solution but I can't seem to figure it out.
I'm new to WP7 programming and Expression Blend modifications in general.

I've created a custom button(template) in Expression Blend that I use in several places in a Windows Phone 7 app. I've deleted the content of the custom button but I can no longer modify the content of the button afterwards.

For instance, if I have several buttons of the same type(based on the template) on the same page I cannot figure out how to modify the content later on.

Here is how the button is handled in the App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="Main1StopButtons" TargetType="Button">
        <Border BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="25">
            <Border.BorderBrush>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF181616" Offset="0.01"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF494444" Offset="0.684"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.BorderBrush>
            <Border.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF0A0909" Offset="0.797"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF272727" Offset="0.003"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text=""/>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

If I modify the "Text" of the TextBlock (to 'Button') then all buttons using the template have the Text of 'Button'.

Thank you for your patience :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TemplateBinding` for this. It says to get a property from a control and put it here to a template:

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
```

Or for something more complex:

```
<ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was a quick fix and now looking at the solution it seems almost too easy :)